# Aditional row in published sheet with locked columns

Tags: google-sheets

I've noted that when I lock (freeze) some columns in a google sheet, in the published view of that sheet appears an aditional empty first row.

This is an example link with edition access:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ry4DGkskr_eZyrtqBDpCFU__ZfTbYSXdp-n3XEfkfew/edit?usp=sharing

I've added an image of the published view where you can see te aditional row. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQNmb_YIlLQal7VbZW29JOuKWq8T_ArC95n37IhMn4HTqDyxWfrk4GM9dTjHYEfPyRAeNeqNcBY9d3w/pubhtml

Do you know a way to eliminate this row?

Comment: It seem fine now, did you check again?

Comment: Checked again and keeps the same. You have to look at the published view in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQNmb_YIlLQal7VbZW29JOuKWq8T_ArC95n37IhMn4HTqDyxWfrk4GM9dTjHYEfPyRAeNeqNcBY9d3w/pubhtml

Comment: Ya, seem like it is a bug

Comment: I unfreeze, then freeze it again, published the document and the extra row is gone. 

If you inspect the HTML code of the page, you will see that the blank space is not a table row, but a header row (class = "row-header freezebar-horizontal-handle)

Comment: I've tried to unfreeze/freeze and then republish, but the blank row is still there for me. If I unfreeze and publish, the row disappears, but when I freeze again, the blank row is again in the published view